# How to show inital value when user focusing on input using IMask

Tags: javascript, imaskjs

I have this mask:

[image]

when the user clicks on the input for the first time, I need to immediately add the input value '+375 ('.
Now when the user enters a number, this value appears '+375 ([user number]', but I need this value '+375 (' to appear as soon as the user clicks on the input

I tried to add an external script, but in this case the cursor is at the beginning of the input

[image]

Comment: [Please do not upload images of code/errors when asking a question.](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551)

Comment: Just add the hardcoded prefix to your input